# How to obtain the last convolutional layer of a model in torchvision for applying grad cam?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution, explainable-ai

I'm using efficient net b0 from torchvision for training a classifier for cifar10. I would like to apply grad cam for generating saliency maps for explaining the predictions.  However, I'm not sure about how to obtain the last convolutional layer of this model. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have not yet been using Grad Cam myself, I am pretty familiar with the concept and I have been interpreting Grad Cam results in my area of expertise.

This example looks quite straightforward in terms how to obtain particular layer of torch's network and use them to generate Activation Maps with Grad Cam: https://jacobgil.github.io/pytorch-gradcam-book/Class%20Activation%20Maps%20for%20Semantic%20Segmentation.html

See this code snipped in particular:

```py
from pytorch_grad_cam import GradCAM

class SemanticSegmentationTarget:
    def __init__(self, category, mask):
        self.category = category
        self.mask = torch.from_numpy(mask)
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            self.mask = self.mask.cuda()
        
    def __call__(self, model_output):
        return (model_output[self.category, :, : ] * self.mask).sum()

    
target_layers = [model.model.backbone.layer4]
targets = [SemanticSegmentationTarget(car_category, car_mask_float)]
with GradCAM(model=model,
             target_layers=target_layers,
             use_cuda=torch.cuda.is_available()) as cam:
    grayscale_cam = cam(input_tensor=input_tensor,
                        targets=targets)[0, :]
    cam_image = show_cam_on_image(rgb_img, grayscale_cam, use_rgb=True)

Image.fromarray(cam_image)
```

and I believe this gets you the layer of interest:

```py
target_layers = [model.model.backbone.layer4]
```

I hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure, because the last convolutional layer can vary in each model. And my main concern is regarding which is the last convolutional layer of the efficient net b0.

Comment: Oh, I see. Honestly, I am not sure which of EfficientNet's layers is the last convolutional one. I the following example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pT1nQinFyBBlg5Ix1ERiNyDTMhK9Fvg4?usp=sharing maybe it is: "(6) ...  (proj): Sequential(
          (conv): Conv2d(1152, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          ...". You would have to do some research on that: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.11946.pdf , https://pytorch.org/hub/nvidia_deeplearningexamples_efficientnet/

Comment: @Zaratruta, hello, been having EXACTLY the same problem with the same purpose of trying to interpret efficientnet_b5 with Grad CAM. Did you eventually find anything?